# Chen Style "Red Fist" application

Tags: tai-chi, application

I thought this would be a good application to ask about, because, while it looks like a simple strike, the deeper application is less apparent.

- What is the application for the Chen Tai Chi technique "Red Fist"

Comment: is this the style you mean?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Whz07ssLFXU

Comment: @HuwEvans Nice link. Always like to see an old-school master doing their thing!  But I was not referring to Red Fist style, but to the tai chi movement, often called "Red Fist Chop".  It's one of the Chen style movements in the 67 Combined Tai Chi form, where I believe it included because it's considered as one of the exemplary & characteristic Chen movements. 
 See [Section 3 in this list of movements](http://elektrikrevue.blogspot.com/2008/09/67-movements-combined-tai-chi-chuan.html)

Comment: Is this any particular tai-chi style?  Chen you say?

Comment: @HuwEvans Chen style, yes, but one can also find it in Shaolin forms.  (Asked about the Tai Chi technique b/c it has multiple applications, like many in that art.  Chen videos I've searched on seem to show only the surface application—wish there was a video of the Chen Village instructor!)  What I'm hoping is that a Chen practitioner sees this and expounds.

Comment: From someone who has studied bagua, isn't actually learning the mechanics of how to strike hard enough? Why does there need to be a more fanciful application?

Comment: @mattm Not fanciful.  (I trained with an old school master who didn't use nonsense words like "energy", unless referring to caloric consumption, which was referred to as "spending money".)  The surface application here is grabbing the back of the head, and smashing the nose with the back of the fist, thus "red fist".  But Chinese internal is heavily based on the strategic principle of deception in general (Sun Tzu), and the deeper application is grabbing the arm and twisting and smashing the back of the fist to break the elbow.

Comment: @mattm Thus masters would teach the surface techniques to "outdoor students", and the deeper techniques to "indoor students".  It is said, not entirely euphemistically, that "every good tai chi movement has multiple applications."

Comment: @mattm For validation, consider that a good shaolin or karate punch is also a *great* elbow strike to an attacker behind.  (Important to balance the force.)  Sometimes multiple applications can be as simple as that.